# Why do fields turn black when using Preview to duplicate or print some pdfs?

Tags: pdf, preview, printing

I've come across a PDF form, whose editable fields turn black when, after completing the form, I try to:

- duplicate
- move
- print, or
- email

the form.

Here's what the form looks like when I download it.
[image]

And here's what it looks like when I try to take any of those actions listed above.
[image]

Note: I didn't create the PDF, and I don't have (or want) Adobe Acrobat professional on my machine.

Has anyone else seen this before?
(I have a workaround, which I'll share below.)

Answer (score 1):

This is workaround, but it does the trick.

Use the print function to "print" a new version of the completed pdf 
[image]

This seems to restore the grey beneath the filled-in text, like so...
[image]